# Get nth non-empty value from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I have a bunch of data that i'm trying to automate getting out of a text file. I can easily append vlaues to numpy arrays and convert the data from strings of numbers into floats of numbers but the problem is that the strings can vary in size. Code snippet can be seen below:

```
pro1 = ' profile1    : (   99.27,    99.19)   20.82      1.75    4.40    0.86    22.05\n'
pro2 = ' profile2    : (  100.31,    99.45)   18.97     10.22    3.00    0.35   -73.86\n'
```

`split_data1 = pro1.split(" ")` 
`split_data2 = pro2.split(" ")`

I want the 3rd, 4th and 5th numbers from these profiles (i.e. 20.82, 1.75, 4.40, 18.97, 10.22, 3.00).
I'm having issues with the splitting of the data as the index I would need changes depending on how many digits the each number has (e.g. 99.27 occupies a different index than 100.31 and 1.75 occupies a different index than 10.22, and this changes the rest of the strings index as well). Also I have around 30,000 of these profiles so I need to automate it. Is there any way to make sure I always get the correct numbers from the string so I can convert it to floats? Is there a eay to get python to give you the nth non empty value in a numpy array?

Comment: maybe you just want `split_data1 = pro1.split()`

Comment: Instead of `split(" ")` try `split()`.  This will remove all contiguous whitespace and you will not be left with any empty strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just `filter` the resulting sequence:

```
import itertools as it

result = tuple(it.islice(filter(None, pro1.split(' ')), 3, 6))
```

Alternatively you can replace multiple whitespace with a single one using regex:

```
import re

result = re.sub(' {2,}', ' ', pro1).split(' ')[3:6]
```

The above approaches generalize to different separators as well, however for the specific use case of splitting on whitespace you can use just `split` without argument:

```
result = pro1.split()[3:6]
```